# Redirecting sed to curl then to file

Tags: shell-script, sed, io-redirection, curl, xargs

I need to download some pages from a site.
What am I trying to do is using `sed` on the site source code to get the links, passing them one by one to `curl` and then output the downloaded file on the right file in right directory.
I will try to get more explicit.
In the page source there's lines like this one:

```
... href="view-source: http://www.site.org/the/file-42.php">
/the/file-42.php </a>"&gt; </span><span> OutDir and some more things ...
```

I'm getting what I need (link - filename - dirname) like this:

```
for i in `cat ~/site_source_file.htm `; do
    echo $i | grep http://www.site.org |
    sed -n 's|^.*\(http://\(www.site.org/the/file-[0-9]*\)\.php\).*.php </a>"&gt; </span><span> \(.*\)|\1 > \3/\2|p' |
        xargs -r 
done;
```

which output is something like this:

```
http://www.site.org/the/file-42.php > OutDir/the/file-42
```

What I need to do is redirect `http://www.site.org/the/file-42.php` content to a file named `/the/file-42` on a directory named `OutDir`
So instead of `xargs -r` alone I thought usign `xargs -r curl` to redirect `curl` output to a file.
But it doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestion how can I redirect 'curl' output to a file this way?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `wget -r`?

Comment: I didn't know this option, but it downloads all the site, not only the file I need. And it doesn't put them in the directories as I want.

Comment: It has lots of flags such as `--accept-regex` and `-D` to specify what files to download exactly. And it does preserve the website directory structure by default.

Comment: In regards to your question, there are a number of problems that I see... First, each line that you're downloading is split by shell, you need to set the field separator with `IFS=$'\n'` to treat them as one line. Then, the for loop can be replaced with just one sed statement. Finally, the reason xargs is not working is because you are trying to feed it complete commands, while what it really needs is a list of strings that it will execute a specified command with. For instance, if you had a list of links you wanted to download, you would invoke it as `cat links.txt | xargs -d "\n" curl`

Comment: No vovick the for loop is ok, the problem was, as Rakesh said, the shell interpretation. Passing arguments with `xargs` don't do the redirection at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your stratagem of using sed<->xargs<->curl doesn't work is that the `>` is interpreted by the `shell` and not `xargs`.

There are a few things you could do here: `1) curl -o` like as shown below:

```
for i in `cat ~/site_source_file.htm `; do
    echo $i | grep http://www.site.org |
    sed -n 's|^.*\(http://\(www.site.org/the/file-[0-9]*\)\.php\).*.php </a>"&gt; </span><span> \(.*\)|curl \1 -o \3/\2|p' |
    bash 
done
```

If you want to use `xargs` then you could:

```
 for i in `cat ~/site_source_file.htm `; do
    echo $i | grep http://www.site.org |
    sed -n 's|^.*\(http://\(www.site.org/the/file-[0-9]*\)\.php\).*.php </a>"&gt; </span><span> \(.*\)|\1 \3/\2|p' |
    xargs -r -n 2 sh -c 'shift $1; curl $1 > $2' 2 1
```

done;

Comment: Nice! I didn't tought about the shell interpretation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create the command completely (`curl url -o file`) and echo it through a pipe as input to `bash`?

```
echo 'curl http://www.di.uminho.pt -o foo' | bash
```

OTH

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you could do:

```
lynx -dump ~/site_source_file.htm |
  perl -ne '/^References/ .. 0 and /^\s+\d+..(view-source: )?(.*)/s and print $2;' |
  parallel -j50 wget
```